# Modify manually PWM of my fan (fan speed)

Tags: power-management, fan, acpi

I configured fanspeed but it detects only one "temp" captor...
In *Gnome Sensors applet*, I can see the temperature of three captors...
The one of my GPU is 75°,
62° for my hard disk
and 32° for my motherboard...

I would like to increase the speed of the fans, just with a command in the terminal... It is possible ?
I know that there is a material solution (buttons on the computer to increase / decrease fans speed), but I'd like to do it with the terminal =)

Thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Packages like `lm-sensors` and `fancontrol` can help you do this safely. If you really want to do it yourself, you can probably find special device files named pwm1, pwm2, etc. in /sys/class/hwmon/*/device/. You can cat them to get the current value or write a number between 0 and 255 to change the fan speed. (But be careful. You can really fry your hardware!)

It's much easier to just use `pwmconfig` from the fancontrol package. Run `sensors-detect` from the lm-sensors package first so that you can see the current temperature and RPM by running `watch sensors`.

Comment: i don't have a /device/ folder but i can read the correct values from "temp_input" and "temp_crit" without a problem. Any ideas?

Comment: On my thinkpad I have three different hwmonX-folders of which only one contains a pwm-file.

Comment: My system is missing the pwm1_enable file. All changes that I make to pwm1 file are overridden almost instantly.